# R,Shiny: Using selectInput() selection to create data frame

Tags: r, shiny

This seems like it should be trivial but I'm obviously missing something. I'd like to have the selection from a `selectInput()` be used to create a data frame. The `selectInput()` produces a character output that doesn't seem to work as an input for creating a data frame. My ui.R and server.R code is below. The `df<-data.frame(input$select, header=TRUE)` line doesn't produce the expected output. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Select Test Dataset"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("select", "Test Dataset", 
                    choices= list("Model Year 2011" = 'cars2011', "Model Year 2012" = 'cars2012'),selected='cars2011')

      ),

      # mainPanel Output
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("value"),
        verbatimTextOutput("type"),
        dataTableOutput(outputId="data")
      )

    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(FuelEconomy)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })
  output$type <- renderPrint({class(input$select)})

  output$data <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(input$select, header=TRUE)
    head(df)
  })




})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `shiny::renderDataTable` instead of `shiny::reactive` when defining `output$data`.

```
output$data <- renderDataTable({
    df <- data.frame(input$select, header=TRUE)
    head(df)
})
```

Comment: is this code working for you? I tested this solution but I still wasnt able to see any output.

Comment: The answer renders a data table, but doesn't display the correct data. The problem is in passing a character string to data.frame. The following R code illustrates the problem:

>chr <- "cars2011"
>class(chr)
[1] "character"
>df<-data.frame(chr,head=TRUE)
>head(df)
         chr     head
1  data2011  TRUE

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: Quinn, The answer I posted provides the desired output. Thank you for your suggestion regarding the use of renderDataTable: it is obviously the preferred method for displaying data and I will use it in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the character string to a data frame name using a switch statement seems to work.

In server.R inserting:

dataset <- reactive({
     switch(input$select,
    "cars2011" = cars2011,
    "cars2012" = cars 2012)
    })

and then using head(dataset()) to output data provides the desired result.